# Obtaining a UK Visitor visa for a disabled student's mother as live-in assistant

Tags: visas, uk, iranian-citizens

I am from Iran. I am a Master's student at City university of London. Although my student visa is approved, I am still in my country because I have a physical disability called Cerebral Palsy, and I cannot travel and live alone. I applied for a visitor visa for my mother to come to the UK temporarily and make the required arrangements with a nursing company. However, her visa has been refused yesterday.

Her refusal letter:
[image: refusal letter p. 1]
[image: refusal letter p. 2]
[image: refusal letter p. 3]
How can I arrange for my mother to be able to accompany and help me?

Comment: What reason(s) did UKVI give for the refusal? Does this answer your question? [UK visa refusal on V 4.2 a + c (and sometimes 'e')](https://travel.stackexchange.com/questions/92121/uk-visa-refusal-on-v-4-2-a-c-and-sometimes-e)

Comment: Based on your question, I've added the Iranian-citizen tag. If you are a citizen of another country, please update your question

Comment: It'd be helpful if you'd post a scan of the refusal letter, with your and your mother's personal details obscured. Use the "edit" button below your question, then select the "moon and mountains" button to add the image to your question.

Comment: Have you talked to your university? Universities are often very good at making arrangements for students with disabilities, and may well be able to set up whatever care you require without your mother visiting.

Comment: Guys, I have uploaded her refusal letter

Comment: I know this is her fault that there are some contradicts in the application form which I filled it and her said in her interview.

Comment: I solved the permission issue. Can you see it? @ajd

Comment: @SimaFaraji Yes it is visible. Though you may still want to use the snipping tool and take screen captures of your letter and put it directly into your question, and black out the personal information.

Comment: I did it for you. Someone just has to approve the edit.

Comment: Anyone can have some pieces of advice? Please don't hesitate to ask if you need any further information

Comment: Ouch, they got her on quite a lot there - discrepancies in application, funds parking, credibility of the application etc.  The link Traveller provides earlier in the comments will help, but you have other issues with this application which might be more difficult to overcome now that they have refused it, as any substantial change in subsequent applications might give cause for concern.

Comment: Have you asked the university? [e.g.](https://www.city.ac.uk/study/fees-and-funding/financial-alternatives/disabled-students-allowances)